# assign output ID to renderdataTable() objects in lapply in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list which contains several data.frames in same format, with these data.frames I would like to make a tablist to show each of the data.frame as a DT::datatable and a plot out of it in below, the following code works fine:

```
createTabs <- function(df) {
    tabPanel(
             renderDataTable(df),
             renderPlotly(volcano_plot(df))
    )}

myTabs <- lapply(myList, createTabs)
return(do.call(tabsetPanel,myTabs))
```

However, this way I did not assign output ID to each of the renderDataTable object, later if I would like to get the user selected rows to do some statistics in the datatable like in this one

[How do I get the data from the selected rows of a filtered datatable (DT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511717/how-do-i-get-the-data-from-the-selected-rows-of-a-filtered-datatable-dt)

It will not be possible because I can't get the output id of those datatables, I wonder if there's a way to assign an output ID to each of the datatables when I create then with renderDataTable() already, or is there any other way round? Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first construct the output objects (so you can name them), and then call them in the creation of your `tabsetPanel`. Working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('my_tabsetpanel')  

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myList = list('dt_1'= head(mtcars,5), 'dt_2' = head(mtcars,5), 'dt_3'= head(mtcars,5))

  # create the tables
  lapply(seq_along(myList),function(x) {
    output[[names(myList)[x]]] = renderDataTable({myList[[x]]})
  })

  # create the plots
  lapply(seq_along(myList),function(x) {
    output[[paste0(names(myList)[x],'_plot')]] = renderPlotly({plot_ly(myList[[x]],x=~mpg,y=~cyl)})
  })  

  # create tabsetPanel 
  output$my_tabsetpanel <- renderUI({
    myTabs = lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x)
    {
      tabPanel(paste0('mytab',x),
               dataTableOutput(names(myList)[x]),
               plotlyOutput(paste0(names(myList)[x],'_plot')))}
    )
    do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now you can also call their selected rows, since the datatables are named. If `MyList` is in fact reactive, you should wrap an `observer` around the two `lapply` statements. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, I did not know one can actually put a tabPanel inside a function, that's magic, thanks :D